# What does ~ mean in Unix Shell Scripting

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I have UNIX server and When I access my shell using Putty.exe (for Windows)

I get Following PATH for public_html directory

```
name@domain.com[~/public_html]#
```

I am excited to know that what does **~** mean in above code

Shell: BASH

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tilde (`~`) indicates the home directory of the user

So if you log in with `root` user (for example) this means

```
/root/public_html
```

If you log in with another user, let's say `hsaka`, it is reasonable to think that this means

```
/home/hsaka/public_html
```

Comment: Is there any difference between (/) and (~)

Comment: @hsaka: of course. `/` means the root directory (so the main directory of your system) where you can find some folders like `etc`, `var`, `usr`, `home`, .... )

Comment: Can you tell me where can I locate directory **usr/bin** in my cpanel. Its there in shell terminal but when i search all file/directories in Cpanel I dont get such directory

Comment: `usr/bin` is always located in `/user/bin`. From cPanel I don't know how you can reach that directory as we should understand what cPanel user you're using and what privileges that user have

Answer (score 0):

**~** is home directory and if you are **root** then it gives root directory.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @Saurabh ohh , So what is the answer???Can you tell me.I gave precise answer to the user and after giving my answer DonCallisto edit his post and mention the root related issue...

Comment: Root's home directory is frequently not the root directory. (The terminology here is slightly confusing. The root account and the root of the directory tree are two separate concepts.)

Answer (score 0):

This is covered in the bash man page under 'Tilde Expansion'. Generally, it is analogous to using the $HOME environment variable.  It is evaluated by the shell so you can use this in scripts that run under bash (or most other *nix shells).  However, Tilde Expansion is not supported globally so its use in other applications may or may not work.